# If $f$ is holomorphic on a domain $D$, and $f$ is bounded on $D$, does this imply that $f'$ is bounded on $D$?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f \leq M$ on $D$, we can use Cauchy's estimate to note that $f'(a) \leq M/r$ where $r$ is the radius of the largest circle around $a$ that is contained in $D$.
Yet, we can make $r$ small by taking $a$ close to the boundary of $D$.
So can $f'$ be unbounded on $D$?

Answer (score 2):

Note: $\sqrt{1-z}$ is holomorphic and bounded on $D = \{z: |z|<1\}$ but its derivative is unbounded there.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You use the "square root" symbol to define a function that you claim is holomorphic. How is the holomorphic square root function defined for complex numbers?

Comment: @KaragounisZ : Choose a branch cut along $[1,\infty)$ to define $\sqrt{1-z}$ in $D$.